# Replace em update, alteração da extensão em nomes de ficheiros

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho uma tabela com imagens, `images`, em que uma dessas colunas (`file_name`) tem nomes de imagens, umas `jpg` outras `png`, o que preciso é alterar, fazer `UPDATE` todas para a extensão `png`, ou seja, alterar qualquer extensão que tenha e colocar `png`.

PS: existem nomes de ficheiros que têm pontos para além do da extenção, ex: "41sUhh.mGDDL.*SY355*.jpg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o [replace()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
update tabela set file_name = replace(file_name, '.jpg', '.png');
```

Só tem que tomar cuidado para não ter mais de uma ocorrência de `.jpg` na sua coluna `caminho_foto`.